# Exporting an SC query result to Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, export, query

I wrote an SC query to show all the services and their state and I can easily display it in a text file. What I want to do is list all this data directly to an Excel worksheet.

How / is this possible?

Comment: Can I assume you don't want to export to a .csv file and then import that?

Answer (score 0):

Excel can 'pull' (fetch from elsewhere) but won't be 'pushed' (accept from elsewhere unsolicited), short of hacking the file. So 'directly' is not possible - but @DaveRook's suggestion is a good one.